# KQL IFF Statement - trying to compare deployments between environments to verify if they are in sync

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitor-workbooks

I'm working on an azure workbook that has a KQL query that shows the latest deployments for my dev, qa and staging environments. My source of truth will be my QA environment tracked by the build revision.

For example

Component1
DEV - QA - STG
rev9 rev4  rev3

Compoent2
DEV - QA - STG
rev2 rev2  rev1

I want to write a KQL Iff statement that basically says... if my dev or stg deployments have the same revision as QA they are in sync.... if dev or stg do not have the same revision as QA they are out of sync. (This means QA will always show as being in sync since it is the source of truth)

What is the easiest way to accomplish this? I extended a column called nSync to track if this is true or not but I can't seem to figure out how to say if Revision == QA.Revision evaluate true so that all environments will show true if they have the same revision as QA.

| extend nSync = iff(Revision == Revision where TenantId == "QA"), "Good", "Bad")
| project nSync, Component,TenantId, Branch, Revision, Pipeline, TimeGenerated
| sort by Component

I expected the table to produce "Good" if the revision in any Tenant had the same revision number as the QA Tenant.

Comment: it would be simpler to understand & answer your question if you were to provide: 1) a sample input datatable (using the [`datatable` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datatableoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer)); 2) the expected output for that input

Answer (score 1):

I have used sample data to get the result.

Below is Sample data with query, assuming the table have atleast 2 columns containing the *Environment* and *Revision*.

```
let tbl = datatable(Environment: string , Revision: string )
[
 "DEV", "2.2",
 "QA", "1.2",
 "UAT", "1.1",
 "PROD", "1.2",
 ];
 let QAVersion = tbl | where Environment == "QA" | project Revision;
 tbl
 | extend nSync = iff(Revision == toscalar(QAVersion),"Good","Bad")
 | project nSync,Revision,Environment
```

**Result**

[image]

> If you have multiple versions stored for an environment across multiple timestamp then you can use `summarize arg_max(Revision) by TimeStamp` which will return latest version for the respective environments.